# Scala macro: argument types of a function reference

Tags: scala, macros

I'm writing a scala macro, which inspects a given function to find it's argument names and types.

```
def hello(i: Int, s: String) = s + i
```

It works so far, if I feed the macro like this:

```
val args: TypeInfo = signature(hello _)
```

But I also want to be able to supply just a reference to the original function:

```
def invokeMacro(f: (Int, String) => String) = signature(f)
invokeMacro(hello)
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

Here is how I obtain the type info within the macro:

```
val typeInfo = TypeInfo(t.filter(_.isDef).collect {
  case ValDef(_, name, typ, _) =>
    name.decodedName.toString -> typ.tpe.toString
})
```

Now I wonder, if it is possible to get hold of the original function 'hello' inside the macro
and extract it's type info. Scrutinizing the information available inside the macro with
the debugger did not yield what is was hoping for.

So I wonder is it possible, if not: why? If it's possible, how?

Comment: Great that it works that well; I'd have expected fresh names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `invokeMacro` is a function, not a macro, it doesn't get its argument's AST, and `signature` just sees `Ident(TermName("f"))` as its argument (or something like that). This is not a `ValDef`, so your match fails. And of course, the name `hello` isn't there in any way (but you could get the type).

To work around this, `invokeMacro` itself would need to be a macro which just generates the `signature(f)` call. Or, more generally, have

```
def invokeMacro0[A](f: () => A) = macro...
def invokeMacro1[A, B](f: A => B) = macro...
def invokeMacro2[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C) = macro...
...
```